# Online Chat using Pooling

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I need help in doing an **online chat**. I already created a simple online chat where one user can communicate to another user and their conversation is saved as a **json file**. The json file is what I am reloading after every 2secs using **setInterval()**. The message the users are sending are appended on the json file by posting it using **ajax** and through php function **fopen and fwrite**(append).

My problem is that the sending/posting process on my ajax is too slow. It takes time before the user see his/her message was send on the chat screen(div). I tried appending the message on the screen to look as if it is already sent but the problem is when the setInterval reloads the chat screen and the new appended message is not yet saved on the json file, the newly sent message will not be included on that reload.

Questions:

1. How can I append the new message faster?
2. How can I queue the multiple post on my ajax when the user is typing and sending message too fast?
3. PS: Is their a better way of creating a online chat? I've read that I am using pooling on my chat and the better way is by using socket but I have no idea on using it. Do you have a better way or better logic?

Comment: Any reason you're not using a database? It would be much easier.

Comment: I am not using database because I thought saving each message will populate my database.

Comment: It *will* populate your database `:)` It won't take up that much more space - probably around 32KB more than a flat file - and you'll enjoy the benefits.

Answer (score 5):

Few Points to consider:

-> Search about Long Poll (COMET)

-> Why do setInterval refreshes the screen, it should just append the new messages from the server

-> If you are using HTML5 based browsers, check Websockets and Server Side Events.

-> Use DB operations on server side, instead of File operations. It will also improve maintainability, consider a case in which 1000 different users are chatting with each other, it will be difficult to maintain those files.

-> Server should send the delta messages which are new, it should not just send the whole conversation again to client to parse and reload.

Comment: Also using a DB might be faster than XML or JSON objects.

Comment: Yes, appending is better than refreshing the entire page. THank you! and with regards to the websockets, I cant use it yet because I needs HTML5 and their is a big chance that the users are not using it.

Comment: I agree DB should be faster then file operations ... Thanks c0d3Junk13.

Answer (score 0):

I just do it recently, here is the code

index.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: index.php"); //
    }

    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        if(trim($_POST['username']) != "") {
            $_SESSION['username'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
            header("Location: index.php"); //
        } else {
            header("Location: index.php"); //
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="zh-CN">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title>chating</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.corner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#main,#login").corner("15px");
</script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {

    //$("#main,#login").corner();

    $("#message").focus();

    $("#logout").click(function() {
        if(confirm("Are you sure to exit this chat?")) {
            window.location = "index.php?logout=yes";
        }
    });

    $("#btnsend").click(function() {

        //$("#chathistory").append("<div>" + $("#message").val() + "</div>");
        //alert($("#chathistory").html());

        if($("#message").val() == "") {
            alert("Please input something !");
            return false;
        }

        $.post("ajax.php", {message: $("#message").val()});

        $("#message").val("");
        $("#message").focus();

        return false;
    });

    $("#message").keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#btnsend").click();

        }
        //alert(e.keyCode);
    });


    function loadChatHistory() {
        var oldscrollHeight = $("#chathistory").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php?type=getmsg",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "xml",  
            success: function(xmlData) {

                var htmlData = "";
                $(xmlData).find("Msg").each(function() {
                    htmlData += '<div><span class="people">' + $(this).find("MsgFrom").text() + "  " +  $(this).find("MsgDateTime").text() +  '</span><p class="content">' + $(this).find("Message").text() + '</p></div>'
                });

                $("#chathistory").html(htmlData);
                var newscrollHeight = $("#chathistory").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;

                if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight) {
                    $("#chathistory").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal');
                }

            }
        });




    }

    setInterval (loadChatHistory, 2500);
});
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    //print_r(var_dump($_SESSION));
?>
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
?>
    <div id="login">
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <label for="username">UserName:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="corner2"/>
            <input type="submit" id="btnlogin" name="btnlogin" class="corner2" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
    } else {
?>
    <div id="main">

        <p id="welcome">Welcome, <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></strong></p>
        <p id="logout"><a href="#">Exit Chat</a></p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="chathistory" class="corner2">

        </div><!-- #chathistory -->

        <div id="userlist" class="corner2">

        </div><!-- #userlist -->

        <div id="chatarea" class="corner2">
            <textarea id="message" class="corner2" rows="2" cols="2"></textarea>
        </div><!-- #chatarea -->
        <div id="send">
            <input type="button" id="btnsend" value="Send!" class="corner2" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div><!-- #main -->
<?php
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

    session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set("PRC");

    if(isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
        $dbh = new pdo("sqlite:./Message.DB");

        if(isset($_GET["type"]))
        {

            if($_GET["type"] == "getmsg") {

                $strXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
                $strXML .= "<Msgs>";

                foreach($dbh->query("select * from (SELECT  * FROM Message ORDER BY MsgID DESC limit 0,500) ORDER BY MsgID ASC") as $row) {
                    $strXML .= "<Msg>";
                    $strXML .= "    <Message>" . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($row[1])) . "</Message>";
                    $strXML .= "    <MsgDateTime>" . $row[2] . "</MsgDateTime>";
                    $strXML .= "    <MsgFrom>" . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($row[3])) . "</MsgFrom>";
                    $strXML .= "</Msg>";
                }

                $strXML .= "</Msgs>";
                echo $strXML;

            } 
        } else {

            $message = $_POST["message"];   
            $message = str_replace("'","''",$message);

            $SQL = "INSERT INTO Message(Message, MsgDateTime, MsgFrom) VALUES('" . $message . "', '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "','" . str_replace("'","''",$_SESSION["username"]) . "')";
            //echo $SQL;
            $dbh->query($SQL);
        }
    }
?>
```

style.css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: LucidaGrande, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, IPAPGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color: #EDE8E2;
}



#main ,#login {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #A8B6D3;

    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; 
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;

    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
}

#login {
    text-align:center;
}

#login input[type="text"] {
    border:0;
    padding:5px;
}

#login input[type="submit"] {
    border:0;
    border:2px solid #5D92D0;
    background-color: #A8B6D3;
    padding:2px;
    font-family: LucidaGrande, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, IPAPGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#welcome {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float:left;
}

#logout {
    text-align:right;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#chathistory {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}

#chathistory span.people {
    color:#008040;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#chathistory p.content {
    margin-left:20px;
}

#userlist {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: 480px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    width:100px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#userlist ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#chatarea {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top:15px;
    height:70px;
    width:470px;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

#message {
    width: 460px;
    height:62px;
    resize: none;
    border: 0;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 10px;

    font-family: LucidaGrande, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, IPAPGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;

    overflow:auto;
}

#btnsend {
    width:120px;;
    height:70px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top:15px;
    border:2px solid #5D92D0;
    background-color: #A8B6D3;
    font-family: LucidaGrande, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, IPAPGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.corner2 {
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

PS, I usd the SQLite database

Answer (score 0):

You should use a database rather than a flat file as there can be issues if trying to read and write a file simultaneously, and it takes unnecessary processing to parse the entire json formatted conversation every two seconds, I'd recommend sqlite as it's easy to set up and doesn't require any special database server software, you can then just do a query to select all messages for the current conversation sent after the last refresh, your queries would be along the lines of:

Fetch messages:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `id` == '".$id."' AND `timestamp` > '".$lastfetch."'");
```

Send message:

```
$timestamp = time();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `chat` (`id`,`message`,`timestamp`) VALUES('".$convoid."', '".$message."', '".$timestamp."')");
echo $timestamp;
```

You'd then save the echoed timestamp into a variable in your javascript, then send it as `$lastfetch` with your next ajax fetch, so your query will get all new messages since the last time it checked.